# java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion

Tags: java

```
if (builderAggregateCalculationsType == AggregateCalculationsType.AGGREGATE_AVERAGE) {
            BigDecimal quarterDivisor = new BigDecimal(3);
            quarterDivisor = quarterDivisor.setScale(
                    aggregateCalculationsNumberOfDecimalPlaces,
                    RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            firstQuarterSum = firstQuarterSum.setScale(
                    aggregateCalculationsNumberOfDecimalPlaces,
                    RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
            secondQuarterSum = secondQuarterSum.setScale(
                    aggregateCalculationsNumberOfDecimalPlaces,
                    RoundingMode.HALF_UP);

            firstQuarterSum = firstQuarterSum.divide(quarterDivisor);
            secondQuarterSum = secondQuarterSum.divide(quarterDivisor);

        }
```

Comment: Seeing this exception: Caused by: java.lang.ArithmeticException: Non-terminating decimal expansion

Comment: I need just divide the firstquartersum and seconfquatersum by 3

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because the division result is producing a `Non-terminating` fraction. Something like `1/3` will produce `0.3333....` which doesn't terminate.

If you can allow some error, you can specify the RoundingMode and use this,

```
firstQuarterSum.divide(quarterDivisor, RoundingMode.HALF_UP); // Or any other rounding mode you prefer.
```